# Mongoose Populate with 2 Collections field other than Id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have 2 Schema

Stock Schema

```
var Stocks = new Schema({
    Symbol : String,
    Name : String,
    MarketCap : Number,
    Sector : String,
    Industry : String
});
mongoose.model('Stocks', Stocks, 'Stocks');
```

Price Schema

```
var Prices = new Schema({
    date : Date,
    symbol : String,
    open : Number,
    close : Number,
    low : Number,
    high : Number,
    volume : Number
});
mongoose.model('Prices', Prices, 'Prices');
```

I need to merge both on `Symbol`  as it the only thing common between 2 collections.

Not getting exactly how to use `.populate()` with this field.

Cannot alter the existing data in Database by creating schema to add `Price ref` in Stock Schema.

Need to find a Particular stock with all prices merged on Symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Populate does not work with the `String` fields. You have to use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation which works as LEFT outer join and extract the data from the referenced collection where both the common fields matched.

```
Stock.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Price.collection.name,
    "localField": "Symbol",
    "foreignField": "symbol",
    "as": "prices"
  }}
])
```